# UITableView not showing when adding it from a custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, class

I have a custom class "`customClass`" that is a subclass `UITextField`. Here is the setup:

```
- (void)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDoder {
    [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self setupView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setupView
{
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 500) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    static NSString *cellID = @"cellID";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }

    [cell.textLabel setText:@"hey"];
    return cell;
}
```

I have a `textField` in the `storyboard`, so I set its' class to the `customClass`.

When I run the app, nothing happened. So in `setupView`, I added the following:

```
[self.superview insertSubview:self.self.tableView
                     belowSubview:self];
```

I still didn't see the `tableView`, so I did this:

```
[self addSubview:self.tableView];
```

And the `tableView` was inside the `textField`, so I was only able to see part of it.

How can I add the `tableView`, so it will display normally?

Comment: You want to show the TableView inside the TextField or on the ViewController?

Comment: on the viewController

Comment: then instead of subclassing to UITextField, use UIView to subclass the custom class

Comment: That's an idea, but I know it's possible to do. If you look at this project, he did the same thing: https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField/blob/master/MLPAutoCompleteTextField/MLPAutoCompleteTextField.m#L4433

Comment: @Paddy is right. Or if you want to use customClass of textField then add tableview directly where you added textField(customClass).

Comment: @SweetAngel What do you mean?

Comment: I mean to say where you have added textField at there directly add tableview to below same textField.

Comment: @SweetAngel I just tried adding it in my mainVC class, and it worked, but isn't it kinda a hack?

Comment: If you think it is kind of hack, then try your solution... :) Best luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to be a implemented to suit a `UITableViewController` and not a `UITextField`.

What you'll need to do is create a `UITableViewController` by dragging one onto the storyboard, and then setting its class to your `customClass`.

An implementation for `UITextField` would be much different, and not what you appear be wanting to achieve.

Good Luck!

Programmatic way:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@interface AppDelegate () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

    UIViewController *controller = [UIViewController new];
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 100, 500) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    [controller.view addSubview:tableView];
    _window.rootViewController = controller;
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

// Your Custom Stuff in a separate class:
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    static NSString *cellID = @"cellID";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }

    [cell.textLabel setText:@"hey"];
    return cell;
}
@end
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to create this as code, not in the storyboard.